# Python- Knapsack that returns possibilities

Tags: python, knapsack-problem, dna-sequence

I am trying to write a knapsack algorithm to generate all possible combinations of four letters (ATGC) and no letter (represented by a space) that's length totals x. This is part of an error correction program for digital data storage I am working on. My current method uses itertools.product, but it generates a massive number of possibilities that takes too long to process. I want to replace this with a knapsack algorithm, but I'm not sure where to start. My current implementation is below.

```
for error in itertools.product(" ATGC", repeat=errors):
    print(error)
    errorTest = list(error).remove(' ')
    print(errorTest)
    if len(errorTest) == constrain:
        for ps in error:
            for pos in errorPos:
                if ps == " ":
                    fseqL[pos] = ""
                else:
                    fseqL[pos] = ps
        ffseq = ""
        ffseq = ffseq.join(fseqL)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to generate all combinations of a specific length is using `itertools.combinations` instead of `itertools.product`. This way you can write

```py
itertools.combinations(" ATGC", constraint)
```

to get all combinations of a specified length.

Comment: It skips some combinations, for my application order does matter. Could I just reverse the sequence?

Comment: This should not skip any combinations. If you need to reverse it you can write `list(itertools.combinations(" ATGC", constraint))[::-1]`, this should als be the same as `itertools.combinations(" ATGC"[::-1], constraint)`.